# Showing certain vector operations/properties imply perpendicularity between particular vectors. l

Tags: linear-algebra

" Let $E$ be any unit vector, that is a vector of norm $1$. Let $c$ be the component
of $A$ along $E$. We saw that $c = A·E$.

Then $A - cE$ is perpendicular to $E$, and $A = A - cE + cE$. Then $A - cE$ is also perpendicular to $cE$. "

How do we get the implications below algebraically? I can see this is true from the picture of the situation, but I'm having hard time showing this purely algebraically.

$1$. $c = A·E -> A - cE$ is perpendicular  to $E$, and $A = A - cE + cE$

$2$. The implication $1 -> A - cE$ is also perpendicular to $cE$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Linearity in the first argument:
   $$(A-cE) \cdot E = A \cdot E - c(E \cdot E) = c - c \cdot 1 = c - c = 0 \implies A-cE \text{ is perpendicular to } E$$
   $$A+cE-cE=A+c(E-E)=A+c(\vec{0})=A$$
2. $$1. \implies 0= c \cdot 0 = c((A-cE) \cdot E)=c(E \cdot (A-cE))=(cE) \cdot (A-cE)$$